# What do I need to do additionally to start X in order not to end in a black screen?

Tags: command-line, terminal, x11, xfce, display-manager

From the Xfce desktop environment in Linux Mint, I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> in order to get into a virtual terminal.

Then I stopped the `mdm` display manager with `killall mdm`. So far, it worked, but once I type X to start the x window system, my screen turns black. I was told this is naturally because I need to do something additionally to get into the X window system.

Comment: Rather than `killall`, certainly a `service stop` would have been preferable (though the service script might do a kill behind the scene).

Comment: Frankly speaking, i do not know how this differs.

Comment: Well,the preferred command might do several other things to help the service terminate properly, and perhaps handle some things outside of the service duty pertaining to the interaction between the OS and the service. That's very generic explanation because in this instance I don't know what actions are being performed.

Answer (score 2):

Typically X is started with the `startx` command or by starting the service associated with your display manager (`mdm` for you), which then starts an X server for you. You can probably fix this by running `service mdm restart` as root on one of your terminals.

Comment: when i type service mdm restart from the terminal, do i get into the x window system without any window manager so i will be without the ability to even move windows?

Comment: The `x` program is a bit analogous to the Unix kernel, in the sense that it works like the program bootstrapping the windowing system, but it does not provide a "shell" functionality. `startx` more or less equates to `init`: it will set things up, and eventually spin up the programs you want to have running first in your session (for instance a window manager). `mdm` is the graphical login interface (a bit like `getty`).

Comment: You'll get the usual graphical login prompt, which will then run your session window manager (xfce) after you've authenticated yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Proper command to start the default display manager in Linux Mint is:

```
sudo service mdm start
```

Analogous is stopping and / or restarting the service.

Just dont `kill` it and you will be fine.